# display block for td element not working in some browsers

Tags: css, html-table

I need to make a responsive `table`. I want to make all `td` elements to behave like a single row in mobile view. I have used

```
td{
     @media (max-width:768px)
        { 
           display:block;
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly fine in google chrome, but doesn't work on mozilla firefox browser. In mozilla `td` element is not taking full width, I have tried `width:100%` for `td` which didnt work. How can I resolve this issue?

**Google Chrome**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

Comment: Have you set table-layout: fixed for table?

Comment: if i use table-layout:fixed then td element just compresses itself to its original width.....so i have tried this and now its working in both chrome and mozilla....

table, thead, tbody, tfoot, tr, th, td {

  @media(max-width:768px)
  {
      display: block; 
  }
}

Comment: setting all table child elements to display:block worked for me...not sure if its a good design practise

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the width: 100% & display:block to all parent elements as well? so

```
td, tr, table, tbody {
    width: 100%;
    display block;
}
```

Comment: After almost an hour of debug, this worked for me. Thank you DM